# Why does my Visual Studio Setup Project launch IE when installation is complete?

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, setup-project

I have this Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project for installing my application. On (clean) Windows 7 32bit installations, it starts Internet Explorer after installing my application.

On my own machine (Windows 7 64bit), this doesn't happen. Do you have an idea what could be the issue here? The default browser on my machine is chrome. On the (clean) 32bit machines it is Internet Explorer 8...

**Update:**
I have just installed Safari on the test machine and set it as the default browser. Now the installer *doesn't* open a browser window. When I set Internet Explorer back to being the default browser, uninstall my application, reinstall it: Bam! Browser window opens again :(

**FIXED:** I was stupid. Now I'm less stupid. All this from r78 to [r79](http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/source/detail?r=79).

Comment: oops! I found the mistake. Somehow I had copied code to perform a process to start http://www.microsoft.com - I am guessing this is a copy/paste issue of a template I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are opening microsoft.com because you copied and pasted code. Ok ok I have no shame, but it would be a shame for that bounty to go to waste (prepares to be voted down) ;)

Comment: actually, Zimm3r, I am upvoting you myself. Please try to find where I copied the code from and I will accept your answer too! (that way, you won't need a second upvote for default bounty assignment ;)

Comment: I guess I will never ever find the location I copied the example installer class implementation from. This really bugs me. Here, go ahead and take the bounty, have a nice day!

Comment: I don't see your code, so kinda hard, but I would love to help, sense it does feel weird not doing anything and getting 200 rep points (well besides the post). Or did you find the installer class (the r79 link; http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/source/detail?r=79)?